# How to access the event handler in another class

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a click event handler in class A with some logic. And now i want to access class A event handler from class B and do some logic so that class B event hadler logic fires first followed by class A event handler.

Example:

```
Class A
private void calculate_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{  this.MyMethod(); }

Class B
private void calculate_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{  // My new code.. (This should trigger first)  this.MyMethod(); }
```

Comment: This seems like a code smell to me. What's your goal? Are you wanting to override the calculate behavior of A in your class B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use event exposed by class A and consumed by class B like we do with Button class. Button exposes click event and in our form class we subscribe for click event being exposed by Button class.

I found this simple example for understanding [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11541/The-Simplest-C-Events-Example-Imaginable)

```
using System;
namespace wildert
{
    public class Metronome
    {
        public event TickHandler Tick;
        public EventArgs e = null;
        public delegate void TickHandler(Metronome m, EventArgs e);
        public void Start()
        {
           // while (true) //uncomment this line if you want event to fire repeatedly
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                if (Tick != null)
                {
                    Tick(this, e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
        public class Listener
        {
            public void Subscribe(Metronome m)
            {
                m.Tick += new Metronome.TickHandler(HeardIt);
            }
            private void HeardIt(Metronome m, EventArgs e)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("HEARD IT");
            }

        }
    class Test
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Metronome m = new Metronome();
            Listener l = new Listener();
            l.Subscribe(m);
            m.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming class B has instance member `A instanceOfClassA` initilized properly with an instance of A:

```
private void calculate_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
  // My new code.. (This should trigger first)  
  instanceOfClassA.MyMethod();
  // other code
}
```

You may also consider inheriting class B from A:

```
class B:A
{
   private void calculate_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
    {
      // My new code.. (This should trigger first)  
      this.MyMethod(); // will come from base class A implementation.
      // other code
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Alexei, i dont want to inherit from class A but i want the access. can i..?

Comment: @Mr.Info
 than you must choose the first option described by Alexei